# svg icons appears pixelated on high DPI

Tags: c++, qt, icons

Some of my SVG icons don't scale properly on scaling a monitor (Win10) or use a highDPI monitor (Win10, Linux, Mac). This applies to icons assigned to a QAction and displayed by QMenu entries or QToolButtons, and icons assigned to QDockWidgets, as shown in the upper part of the attached screenshot.

The icons in the lower part are painted in the derived paintEvent(..) and render perfectly.

[image: Pixelated action icons]

Using the option `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps);` The system seams to use some scaling heuristic on a pixmap so the icon becomes somehow edgy:

[image: Edgy action icons]

Is there any way to make qt redraw the icon on the SVG base without the need to derive all icon-showing classes?

Sincerely 
JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with SVG icons too. Turns out for me it was caused by an aspect ratio difference between the SVG file and what I tried to render it as. I tried to render as a square but my SVG file was not square. Setting square dimensions in the SVG file fixed it.